# Does "&&" in an if statement affects the time complexity?

Tags: performance, if-statement, time-complexity

Let's just say if there was an if statement like

```
if(arraylist.indexOf(n) < 14 && arraylist.indexof(m) < 20) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Would the if statement be `O(n)` or `O(n^2)`? The time complexity of indexOf(n) is `O(n)`. I tried searching the answer on google but can't seem to find it.

Comment: O(2n) = O(n), you use indexof 2 times so you still get the same complexity

Comment: The time complexity of evaluating the `if` condition is O(N), where N is the size of the list.

Comment: Doing two O(n) operations is O(2n) = O(n), not O(n^2).

Comment: If indexOf (n) is in O (n), then the whole if Statement is O (2n) which is still O (n).

Comment: Instead of using arraylist, use set if your input doesn't have duplicates.

Comment: @Sulthan. The time complexity is unrelated to `n` or `m`. It is `O(N)` in the length of the array, not the size of the array values.

Comment: @Thilo You are right of course. Shouldn't think without coffee.

Comment: The time complexity of this expression might very well be completely dominated by whatever `doSomething` does.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a language tag here, but I'll assume it supports short-circuiting (most do).

The complexity with be whatever `arraylist.indexOf` is times 2.  So, if you're correct and the complexity is `O(n)`, the complexity of your `if` (assuming no short-circuiting) is `O(2n)` (and since you'll typically simplify complexity by dropping constants, `O(n)`).

Answer (score 0):

It is not unreasonable to be worried about hidden performance implications of a using O(N) function. However, in this case, there is not additional penalty. Worst case occurs when the `indexOf` is called for both sides of the `&&`. The time complexity does not change in this case, since the O(N) is applied at most twice.

I have encountered hidden complexity issues in using concatenation functions, where the concatenation requires traversal of the original value before appending the additional data (e.g., C's `strcat`). A caller that is unaware of the traversal is occurring may write a loop that performs the concatenation on each iteration, not knowing this is triggering an order of magnitude increase in time complexity.